# _worker.default is not a constructor in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to use a web worker in functional components, but getting this error

```
_worker.default is not a constructor
```

here is my code
https://codesandbox.io/s/headless-hooks-ns595?file=/src/App.js

```
export default function App() {
  const { Provider } = c;

  useEffect(() => {
    worker = new HomeWorker();
    worker.addEventListener("message", event => {
      console.log("evbt");
    });
    worker.postMessage("ppp");
  }, []);

  return (
    <Provider value={"kkkkkkkkk"}>
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      <Pqr />
    </Provider>
  );
}
```

Comment: You can add worker-loader as a dependency while loading workers in the js/ts files

Answer (score 1):

In the above code, you are making mistake on import and object creation. For ES6 modules import, you have to modify your code as:

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import { c } from "./context";
import Pqr from "./pqr";
import * as worker from "./worker";
//let worker; no need of this anymore

 export default function App() {
  const { Provider } = c;

  useEffect(() => {
    //worker = new HomeWorker(); no need of this anymore
    worker.addEventListener("message", event => {
      console.log("evbt");
    });
    worker.postMessage("ppp");
  }, []);



 return (
    <Provider value={"kkkkkkkkk"}>
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      <Pqr />
    </Provider>
  );
}
```